# What is the best way to interface with DynamoDB in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-dynamodb

I'd like to setup a Wordpress site but be able to query and display results from a DynamoDB table within a Wordpress page. I haven't started the development yet and wanted to see if anyone had advice on the best way to approach?

Custom Wordpress plugin?
Specific library to leverage to interface with DynamoDb?

Appreciate any help/direction.

Comment: My gut instinct is to make your Dynamo stuff in a file, and link it somewhere using an `iframe`. Having  the same page interacting with two DB formats, sounds like a world of pain.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. I'm going to play with it a bit and see what works out. I'll post my findings here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked with a contractor on this and created a plugin for Wordpress that seems to work well for displaying info from DynamoDB. I need to work on it more to get filtering working properly, but wanted to wrap this up as it definitely seems like the best approach.

I have a prototype of a Wordpress plugin that I'm open sourcing so that others can benefit from it. You can get the code here: https://github.com/coreygans/dynamodb-wordpress

It definitely isn't best practices, but it is functional. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

A route I have taken recently is to make a data connector that copies data from WP to dynamo on the save_post function. I then use lambda to be the frontend to the site so the page seen by non-admin users is served from dynamo and lambda and never even touches WP. I still keep a WP instance running on a small VM so they can do admin functions.