# Wordpress and AWS API Gateway connection?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

internet. I am trying to create an application that allows people to create users. I am a computer noob and was wondering how I would do it. I want people to plug in their information through my WordPress site into DynamoDB.

What should I do?

I have already created an API and function within AWS and am wondering if there is any plugin available. If not, what would be the best course of action?

Comment: Hello @Osiris.N , can you please provide more information ? What service had you used to create the API/function on AWS ?

Comment: *"I want people to plug in their information through my WordPress site into DynamoDB."*  Unfortunately, it's not clear what this actually means in real terms, so it might be helpful if you provide more detail so we can understand exactly what you want to accomplish.  Note also that Stack Overflow doesn't entertain questions asking for recommendations of a plugin/tool/library/book/service/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as I know there is no Plugin for WordPress. However, this guy made a functional WordPress plugin. Here is GitHub link
https://github.com/coreygans/dynamodb-wordpress

and there is another discussion about this topic.

[What is the best way to interface with DynamoDB in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719594/what-is-the-best-way-to-interface-with-dynamodb-in-wordpress)