# Fetch audio,video,pdf from AWS S3 Server using DynamoDB to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am working on a WordPress Website which has a mobile app built in Flutter.

We use AWS S3 server for uploading video, audio and pdf of lessons. In AWS S3 there are hierarchy of different folder structures as per different languages and different chapters.
For eg:

```
Layer 1 English Language, 
    Layer 2 pdf
        Layer 3 lesson1
            Layer 4 pdf file
        Layer 3 lesson2
            Layer 4 pdf file
    Layer 2 audio
        Layer 3 lesson1
            Layer 4 audio file
        Layer 3 lesson2
            Layer 4 audio file
    Layer 2 video
        Layer 3 lesson1
            Layer 4 video file
        Layer 3 lesson2
            Layer 4 video file
Layer 1 Spanish Language, 
    Same Structure as above
Layer 1 German Language
    Same Structure as above
```

Using this structure from S3 how can I fetch audio, video and pdf file to WordPress Website?
Plugin like **AWS for WordPress** are not supporting with WordPress latest version 5.8.3

Also I have referred below link: [What is the best way to interface with DynamoDB in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719594/what-is-the-best-way-to-interface-with-dynamodb-in-wordpress)

Comment: Updated my question for better understandings

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how DynamoDB is entering into the picture. But since you are pulling from an S3 Bucket, as long as that bucket is publicly accessible, you can just download directly from it, using the prefix structure you outlined.

If you want to use some more logic for listing, you can use the [AWS SDK for Javascript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/). That would allow you to list all the objects at a given prefix. You could use [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) to retrieve objects from a given prefix, too.

---

In addition, here is an AWS blog post that may be of interest on the topic. [Deploying a highly available WordPress site on Amazon Lightsail, Part 2: Using Amazon S3 with WordPress to securely deliver media files](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/deploying-a-highly-available-wordpress-site-on-amazon-lightsail-part-2-using-amazon-s3-with-wordpress-to-securely-deliver-media-files/)

And a photos example from AWS documentation. [Viewing photos in an Amazon S3 bucket from a browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/s3-example-photos-view.html)