# Connecting AWS DynamoDB to external Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently running a scheduled webscraping script on AWS using a Docker image scheduled through EventBridge, where the results of this webscraping script are stored in a DynamoDB database. This webscraping script tracks the prices through time of some items on a website.

I also have my own external website unrelated to Amazon/AWS which runs Wordpress, and my idea is that, for each item whose prices I webscrape, I would like a unique page on my website which shows the price through time of the corresponding item in the form of a line chart.

My question is: how can I access the contents of my AWS DynamoDB database from my external Wordpress website? I have seen this post:

[What is the best way to interface with DynamoDB in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719594/what-is-the-best-way-to-interface-with-dynamodb-in-wordpress)

but apparently it is not maintained so I would prefer to not use that route. Any other suggestions for externally accessing DynamoDB (or indeed any SQL database on AWS) that is secure and well-maintained would be much appreciated.

Comment: A better solution might be to write a JSON file containing the history of prices, by date, to S3. Make that publicly readable and have the web page fetch it. No API calls needed from the front-end.